# Is it okay to move around references to avoid heavy copy constructor calls?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, object-reference

Let's say, we want to **reverse an array**, like in this function.

For each swapping of two elements, **the copy constructor**, **destructor** and **two copy assignments** are made.

```
template<class T>
void Reverse(T *arr, int size)
{
    T *leftItem = arr;
    T *rightItem = &arr[size - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++, leftItem++, rightItem--)
    {
        T swap = *leftItem;         // Copy constructor
        *leftItem = *rightItem;     // Copy assignment
        *rightItem = swap;          // Copy assignment
    }                               // Destructor
}
```

This seems horrific. So I came up with an idea and I'm not sure whether it's for the better or worse, since I'm practically bypassing all type safetly and conventions here.

But on the other hand, it avoids copy operations that, depending on the type, could be heavy.

```
template<class T>
void ReverseUsingMemcpy(T *arr, int size)
{
    char *swap = new char[sizeof(T)];
    T *leftItem = arr;
    T *rightItem = &arr[size - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++, leftItem++, rightItem--)
    {
        memcpy(swap, (char*)leftItem, sizeof(T));
        memcpy((char*)leftItem, (char*)rightItem, sizeof(T));
        memcpy((char*)rightItem, swap, sizeof(T));
    }

    delete[] swap;
}
```

So, is my approach suitable, if the type of `<T>` might be any class type? What are the benefits, or what are the reasons to really avoid this? Is there a preferred way to move around the contents of structs without breaking anything?

Note: I'm aware of the `std::vector` type, but I want to also understand references and type-safety more.

Comment: `memcpy` is only valid for trivially copyable types, so your improved function is only valid for a small subset of types.

Comment: For reference you can see how the big three do it through the implementation links at the bottom of the reference to `std::reverse` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse.

Comment: the prefered way is `std::swap`

Comment: Use [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).  If the compiler implementors know of a super fast way of swapping certain types, they would have written it already in one of the `std::swap` specializations.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai or just `std::reverse`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your proposed solution is safe only for trivially-copyable types (that is, those that do not have a user-defined copy constructor or copy-assignment operator).

Even when dealing with trivially-copyable types, there's no reason to use `memcpy` in this case.  It's less readable and no more performant than simply using the assignment operator.

Consider a very simple (useless) example where your proposed solution would fail:

```
struct SelfRef
{
    SelfRef* self_;

    SelfRef() : self_{this} {}
    SelfRef(const SelfRef&) : self_{this} {}
    SelfRef& operator=(const SelfRef&) { return *this; }  // no-op
};
```

Copying such an object via `memcpy` would directly copy the `self_` field, bypassing the copy constructor or copy-assignment operator and result in `self_` pointing to a different location than `this`. [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58e069d05fb716fd).

In general, copy constructors and copy assignment operators exist to maintain the invariants of your classes when they're copied.  Bypassing the assignment operator of a class that has one can and will quickly lead to those invariants being violated and the assumptions that your classes make about their state becoming incorrect.

---

The correct way to swap two objects is to use an appropriate `swap` function that is appropriately optimized for the type being swapped.  The usual way to do this is to pull [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) into the local namespace and let ADL choose a better `swap` function if possible:

```
template<class T>
void Reverse(T *arr, int size)
{
    T *leftItem = arr;
    T *rightItem = &arr[size - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++, leftItem++, rightItem--)
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(*leftItem, *rightItem);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/932249c53e94c238)

That way, you can provide a `swap` function specialized for your type in the same namespace as that type and it will get found by ADL while standard library types, built-in types, and types without an optimized `swap` function will fall back to `std::swap` (which may also have optimized versions for different categories of types).

You could also use [`std::iter_swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap), which implements those same semantics for you when using iterators:

```
template<class T>
void Reverse(T *arr, int size)
{
    T *leftItem = arr;
    T *rightItem = &arr[size - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++, leftItem++, rightItem--)
    {
        std::iter_swap(leftItem, rightItem);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e22e54cec5b2a41a)

---

Of course, in the real world you should just use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) instead of rolling your own `Reverse` function at all.

Comment: +1 for the details, that's what I was curious about. Yeah, there would not be a copy constructor, if the class consist of primitive types. And that copy constructor *is* faster than memcpy. I just haven't thought about the possible invariants.